# Why does my RHadoop Installation cause errors in dyn.load?

Tags: r, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, rhadoop

I need to install RHadoop on my Ubuntu operating system. When I install the rmr2 package I am having this error

```
 library(rmr2)
Loading required package: Rcpp
Loading required package: RJSONIO
Loading required package: digest
Loading required package: functional
Loading required package: stringr
Loading required package: plyr
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/mahi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rmr2/libs/rmr2.so':
  libRcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rmr2’
```

---

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Is Rcpp installed?
What is the output of 
`ldd /home/mahi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rmr2/libs/rmr2.so`?
Were there any error messages or warnings when you installed the package?

Comment: the way i had to install the package was i had to copy the rmr2 library file into the directory of R. I did this because installing rmr2 directly directly in R did not work. Also, I think Rcpp is installed. It is in the library folder of R.

Comment: I get this error now after I reinstalled Rcpp

Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/mahi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rmr2/libs/rmr2.so':
  /home/mahi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rmr2/libs/rmr2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4Rcpp8internal14r_vector_startILi10EEEPNS_6traits12storage_typeIXT_EE4typeEP7SEXPREC

Comment: Copying shared libraries is usually a bad idea: they tend to depend on specific versions of other libraries -- if the versions do not match, you end up with that kind of error message. The easiest is to install `rmr2` from source.